# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.0.4

Tags: firebase

I looked at some articles on Stack Overflow regarding the problem but they haven't worked. The problem is that my build failes to resolve:

> com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.0.4

I'm using android studio to make my app and I'm trying to implement the Firebase Firestore into it.

Here is the code in my build.gradle for my Module:App file:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.0.4'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
}
```

I have no idea what's going on. Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial release of Firestore was 11.4.2 in October 2017.  See the [Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).